# NumberOpsDriver.java:35: error: no suitable method found for add(int)

Tags: java, arraylist

This is a driver program that adds the indicated code

(described in the // comments) so that it does the following: prompts the users for a list of
numbers (ints) separated by a space followed by the number 0; reads the first number in the list;
enters a loop and while the number is not 0, creates a NumberOperations object, adds the
NumberOperations object to an ArrayList called numOpsList, then read the next number in the
list (i.e., iterates through the loop).  Once the value of 0 is read from the list, the loop terminates. 
Now using a second while loop, print out each NumberOperations object in the ArrayList along
with its “odds under” and its “powers of 2 under”.

I receive the error on line 35:

```
no suitable method found for add(int)
         numOpsList.add(input);
                   ^
    method Collection.add(NumberOperations) is not applicable
      (argument mismatch; int cannot be converted to NumberOperations)
    method List.add(NumberOperations) is not applicable
      (argument mismatch; int cannot be converted to NumberOperations)
    method AbstractCollection.add(NumberOperations) is not applicable
      (argument mismatch; int cannot be converted to NumberOperations)
    method AbstractList.add(NumberOperations) is not applicable
      (argument mismatch; int cannot be converted to NumberOperations)
    method ArrayList.add(NumberOperations) is not applicable
      (argument mismatch; int cannot be converted to NumberOperations)"
```

Any help?

```
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.util.ArrayList;

/**
 * Demonstrates the NumberOperations class.
 */
public class NumberOpsDriver {

   /**
    * Reads a set of positive numbers from the user until the user enters 0.
    * Prints odds under and powers of 2 under for each number.
    *
    * @param args - Standard commandline arguments
    */
   public static void main(String[] args) {

      Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);

      // declare and instantiate ArrayList with generic type <NumberOperations>
      ArrayList<NumberOperations> numOpsList = new ArrayList<NumberOperations>();

      // prompt user for set of numbers
      System.out.println("Enter a list of positive integers separated "
      + "with a space followed by 0:");

      // get first user input using in.nextInt()
      int input = in.nextInt();
      // add a while loop as described below: 
      // while the input is not equal to 0 
      // add a new NumberOperations object to numOpsList based on user input
      // get the next user input using in.nextInt()

      while (input != 0)
      {
         numOpsList.add(input);
         input = in.nextInt();
      }

      int index = 0;
      while (index < numOpsList.size()) {
         NumberOperations num = numOpsList.get(index);
         System.out.println("For: " + num);
         System.out.println("\tOdds under:\t" + num.oddsUnder());
         System.out.println("\tPowers of 2 under:\t" + num.powersTwoUnder());

         index++;
      }
   }
}
```

Comment: your list is of numberops type and you are using int as input

Comment: The instructions say "add a new NumberOperations object to numOpsList based on user input", not "add the user input".  So you have to create a new `NumberOperations` object, _based on_ the input.

Answer (score 1):

```
numOpsList.add(input);
```

you are using a generic ArrayList to store a list of instances of`NumberOperations`. what you are doing is trying to add an `int`.

convert your input to a NumbersOperations instance and add it or simply use `ArrayList<Integer>`

Moreover you need not force use `0` to mark the end of input. `Scanner.hasNext()` will return boolean false if there is nothing to read

**EDIT 1**

```
ArrayList<Integer> list = new ArrayList<Integer>();
list.add(2);
System.out.print(list.get(0));
```

Comment: `NumberOperations` is the name of the class and methods, when I change `NumberOperations` to `Integer` it tells me that it can not find the symbol for the methods

Comment: Yes, he does have to use 0 to mark the end of the input.  That's what the instructions say to do.

Answer (score 0):

I got it to work properly, I had to do what @ajb said.

```
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.util.ArrayList;

/**
 * Demonstrates the NumberOperations class.
 */
public class NumberOpsDriver {

   /**
    * Reads a set of positive numbers from the user until the user enters 0.
     * Prints odds under and powers of 2 under for each number.
     *
    * @param args - Standard commandline arguments
    */
   public static void main(String[] args) {

      Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);

      // declare and instantiate ArrayList with generic type <NumberOperations>
      ArrayList<NumberOperations> numOpsList
         = new ArrayList<NumberOperations>();

      // prompt user for set of numbers
      System.out.println("Enter a list of positive integers separated "
                        + "with a space followed by 0:");

      // get first user input using in.nextInt()
      int input = in.nextInt();
      // add a while loop as described below: 
    // while the input is not equal to 0 
         // add a new NumberOperations object to numOpsList based on user input
         // get the next user input using in.nextInt()

      while (input != 0)
      {
         NumberOperations newOp = new NumberOperations(input);
         numOpsList.add(newOp);
         input = in.nextInt();
      }

      int index = 0;
      while (index < numOpsList.size()) {
         NumberOperations num = numOpsList.get(index);
         System.out.println("For: " + num);
         System.out.println("\tOdds under:\t" + num.oddsUnder());
         System.out.println("\tPowers of 2 under:\t" + num.powersTwoUnder());

         index++;
      }
   }
}
```